# NoClassDefFoundError with GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging
```

In my IntentService called from a Gcm Broadcast Receiver created following this guide:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

I'm including play-services as dependence in Gradle.

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
}
```

What could cause this issue?

EDIT:
I'm using a real phone, Android JellyBean 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved using those steps:

- Sync with Gradle
- Rebuild Project
- Generate APK and Run again.